# How to run multiple select query’s asynchronously and collect all result in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, asynchronous, jdbc

I have more than 50 query’s all select with different tables 
I need to execute all list of query’s asynchronously and collect all results as list of map in spring boot
Can anyone advise wat is the best approach to achieve this

Comment: `List<Query> queries; queries.parallelStream(q->{run query put results in map })`

Answer (score 0):

The latest approach is reactive programming:

https://spring.io/blog/2016/06/07/notes-on-reactive-programming-part-i-the-reactive-landscape

Have a look at the Spring 5.0 documentation for WebFlux

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/html/web-reactive.html

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple alternatives:

1. RxJava
2. Spring Reactor (flux)
3. Streams (java 8)
4. Flow (java 9)
5. Others

Since you are developing with spring boot I would choose Spring Flux. If you want to call a rest service and execute each internal service in paral·lel you should implement `subscribe` and `zip` method like:

```java
Flux < String > result1 = Flux.just(something1);
Flux < String > result2 = Flux.just(something2);

Flux < String > viewResult = Flux.zip(result1, result2, (key) - > key);
```

Comment: Do we have any sample code for that above code was for two separate query’s .. but my case I have List<query> how to do in spring flux plz provide a solution